# Windows task scheduled powershells script that uses powercfg.exe prevents system from sleeping

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

Long story short, I have a task scheduled to execute a PS script ever 15 minutes that is checking electricity spot price. When it's higher than I want, it sets

```
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-ac 60
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-dc 60
```

..meaning that my PC should go to sleep after 60 minutes of idling.

For some reason, it seems, altering the timeout perhaps cancels the current timeout? It works when I tested it with 5 and 10 minutes, and hitting the script every 3 minutes, but when I set the value to a hour or two, my computer will never sleep.

Troubleshooting steps taken: Logging every time the powershell script runs, with the value of sleep set into config. Logging `powercfg -requests` to see that indeed nothing is preventing sleep, and finally logging wether the API call made by the scripts fails or not.

Edit: I can also see that the set value is reflected in plan settings properly

[image]

Comment: Though I could not find a citation for this, I believe the Windows OS standby-timeout limit is 30 minutes. You could test this at 29 and 31 minutes to confirm that. If you do, you might post it as a useful answer -- built-in Windows ;limit.

Comment: You don't have the Task Scheduler job option of `Wake the computer to run this task` from the **"Conditions"** tab checked, right? You might also play around with `Start the task only if the computer is idle for` options as well and see if that makes any impact with various configurations. Screen shot --> https://i.imgur.com/OniCTOT.png

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's not correct. It's pretty lax in what it lets you set. Even via the UI (I added an image).

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I have not enabled waking up the computer to run tasks, and actually I've disabled allowing the PC to wake up for any tasks. I will test the "idle for" option.